# Best way to interact with the data inside QTableView

Tags: database, qt

I got a `QTableView` looks like the following:

[image]

Now I have 2 different functions (`Q_SLOT`) that do things according to the selected piece of data.

In order to make the table more intuitive, I've done some research and have been considering adding buttons (on column 1 & 2 respectively) to send the signal about which piece of data has been chosen to be the target.

In brief, I am looking for a **signal** that contains a 2-dimensional information: ***which function to use***, and ***which piece of data(row) has been chosen***. While this could be done outside the table, but I am not considering it since I want the application more intuitive to use.

The number of data counts up to 400~500. In addition to buttons, is there any better *Qt-way* to work this out? Any directions are welcome, coarse ideas are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons can be added as [delegates](http://qtadventures.wordpress.com/2012/02/04/adding-button-to-qviewtable/). They are visual mockups at that point - they look like buttons, but they don't act like buttons. The delegate can create a real button widget when the cell is entered. It's then a simple matter to set some properties on the button to indicate the function and row. Recall that `QObject` has a flexible property system - see the `setProperty` and `property` methods. All widgets are `QObject`s.

The receiver of the button's `clicked` signal can use the `sender()` method to access the sending button instance, and read the properties. You can also subclass the `QPushButton` and emit a custom signal upon the button being clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the QSignalMapper class which collects a set of parameterless signals, and re-emits them with integer, string or widget parameters corresponding to the object that sent the signal. So you can have one like:

```
QSignalMapper * mapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
QObject::connect(mapper,SIGNAL(mapped(int)),this,SLOT(function1(int)));
```

When adding your buttons in each row of table view, you can connect the clicked() signal of the button to the map() slot of QSignalMapper and add a mapping using setMapping so that when clicked() is signaled from a button, the signal mapped(int) is emitted:

```
QPushButton * but = new QPushButton(this);
but->setText("Function1");

QObject::connect(but, SIGNAL(clicked()),mapper,SLOT(map()));
mapper->setMapping(but, rowIndex);

ui->tableView->setIndexWidget(model->item(rowIndex,column)->index(),but);
```

This way whenever you click a button in a row, the mapped(int) signal of the mapper is emitted containing the row number.